# Fixing my dog's relationship with me after I hit her

Tags: dogs

I have a 12-year-old giant French poodle. She is almost blind but still sees well. She does not like to eat dog food, only human food, and it cannot be given to him because she vomits.

She was being very disturbing, barking and banging his head on doors to get me to feed her. I got upset and hit her with a shoe, and her reaction was to go to his bed to hide, so I locked her in it. She escaped from his confinement, and when she saw me take my shoe off again, she went scared to her bed. I leaned out so she wouldn't be afraid of me, but she didn't want to see me.

Now I feel bad because I am afraid that my relationship with her will turn bad, and she needs affection because he is at the end of his life. How can I fix my relationship with her?

Comment: Welcome to Pets SE, please never hit your dog again no matter how annoying or disturbing she is. Dogs need our love and are completely dependent on us, owners; please remember that she never does anything maliciously nor out of spite, she is just following her instincts which tell her what to do.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I get her love back if she don't want to see me

Comment: I am not experienced with dogs, so we need to wait a little until someone else answers your question; but please don't worry because we have some highly experienced dog people on the site.